# why my webview is opend in a own browser

Tags: android

I have a android code like this:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.com");
```

the problem is, when I start the app, it is opend in a new browser intend and not in my webView of the app.

how to avoid this?

Comment: You mean the website is opened in a new browser, instead of your own.

Comment: You need to add a webView client and override function 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading', then all your subsequent urls will open in your own webView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a WebViewClient. This will prevent the default browser to open the URL (or get a selection dialog when there is no default)

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

More information can be found on Android website: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

With the WebViewClient you can do more things, like preventing to load an URL, or change the URL.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```